# Pip says it installed a package but python doesn't allow me to use the module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a package that I made called `inputapi`. I used the python documentary and have installed it before.

I uninstalled it so I could upgrade it but now I get this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'inputapi' has no attribute 'menu'
```

VSCode says nothing about the functions existing in the first place, I checked the src and the .py file is there, anyone know why this just stopped working?

Edit: Here is the code that is calling the package

```py
import inputapi as inp

cache = {
    "1234": "1+2+3+4",
    "0235": "0+2+3+5",
    "1117": "1+1+1+7",
    "1137": "1-1+3+7",
    "1239": "(1+2)÷3+9",
    "1569": "9-5+6÷1",
    "1358": "8÷1+5-3",
    "1679": "9-6+7÷1",
    "0146": "6+4+0×1",
    "1459": "1×9+5-4",
    "1128": "1+2+8-1",
    "1235": "2+3+5×1",
    "1789": "(1+7)÷8+9",
    "0367": "0×6+3+7",
    "1248": "4*1+8-2"
}

inp.menu("Yes", "No", clearOnLoad=True, clearWhenDone=True, title="Working?")
```

(Since I noticed this early in the development of the script I had `menu()` called as debug)

Here is the file tree for those wondering

```
Input API Pack
│   pyproject.toml
│   README.md
│   LICENSE
│
├───dist
│       inputapi-1.0.3-py3-none-any.whl
│       inputapi-1.0.3.tar.gz
│
├───src
│   └───inputapi
│           inputapi.py
│           __init__.py
│
└───tests
```

Comment: Note that there is no problem finding `inputapi`. The problem is missing `inputapi.menu`. Without more debuging details. e.g. the source code and how you try to use it and full traceback is impossible to tell more.

Comment: How is your script called?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I made an edit to demonstrate how it's called by a script that is not in the package

Comment: So your package is called inputapi and it imports inputapi? Or is the inputapi you are showing the package imported by something else? Where exactly is menu defined - in inpotapi/init or inputapi/inputapi?

Comment: @MisterMiyag It's a script that is contained outside the package like how C:\ and D:\ are different but are both accessed, the menu is defined inside the inputapi.py but python says it doesn't exist at all although earlier versions have this work the way it was designed for.

Comment: If it’s inside inputapi.py then the proper import is `from inputapi import inputapi as inp`.

Answer (score 0):

Since inputapi is inside the inputapi package the import has to be phrased as

`from inputapi import inputapi as inp`

Answer (score -1):

Try to check documentation, maybe this function has been removed from module at last version, try to compare version in documentation and your, try to install other version:

`pip install module==version`

And if everything do not helping you, check module in:

`PythonPath\Lib\site-packages\inputapi\__init__.py`

and fix function at module as you wish

Comment: The function has not been removed, I checked the documentation.

Comment: Try to find function at module